# Android phone, not longer working as a debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb

I have a HTC desire as i've been developing on for 1 year. Today i was debuggning, did some changes in the code and tried to run it again but, Eclipse wouldn't regognize my phone. I tried to reconnect the USB cable, tried to turn off/on the USB debugging option in phone-settings. I tried to restart ADB, tried to restart both phone and computer, with no luck.
I tried on an other phone, and it worked normal. So, im guessing the problems is at my desire.

It seems weird since it worked perfectly 2 hour ago. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: When you use the command line and issue the command 'adb devices', having debugging enabled on the phone, what does it show ?

Comment: hmm...it only shows the emulator

Comment: whas OS do you use on your computer, windows, I suppose?

Comment: yes, windows 7! I will try to connect phone to another pc, see if that works better. If not its the phone, If, its the driver?

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't seem to like the USB drivers for Android phones much.  As I mentioned in my answer, you might want to check device manager to see if your phone shows up as an unknown device and tell it which driver to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat I'd check 3 things:
1) Did you check to make sure that USB debugging is still enabled under the developer settings?  I don't know why you would have changed them, but perhaps something happened without you knowing it.
2) If you're developing on Windows, did the driver for your device install properly?  If you're developing on one phone, and the switch to another, sometimes Windows tries to use the wrong driver and you'll have to go into the device manager and update to the proper driver
3) From a command line you can try "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server" to try and resync the process

Comment: Nothing happened when i tried to kill/start server. I don't know about the drivers, they should work. But I will reinstall them!